# Trying to make my SUBSCRIBE button at bottom of form

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mailchimp

I have written some css code and all looks good on desktop but on mobile all is okay except the SUBSCRIBE button which ends up not at bottom of the form but at the bottom line of the multiple choice questions.

```css
.vertical-center {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 65%;
  left: 35%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px){
  #mcemail {
  width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="mcemail"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <p>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="first name"
    required="">
</p>
<p>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="LNAME" placeholder="last name"
    required="">
</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <p>
    <label>Email address: 
        <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Your email address" required />
</label>
</p>  
              <p>
    <label>Which List to signup for</label>
    <label>
        <input name="_mc4wp_lists[]" type="checkbox" value="Cotacachi"> <span>Cotacachi</span>
    </label>
        <input name="_mc4wp_lists[]" type="checkbox" value="Quito"> <span>Quito</span>
    </label>
    <label>
    <label>
        <input name="_mc4wp_lists[]" type="checkbox" value="Delivery (Cuenca, Olon, Manta, Puerto Lopez, Puerto Cayo, Bahia, Crucita, Ayampe)"> <span>Delivery (Cuenca, Olon, Manta, Puerto Lopez, Puerto Cayo, Bahia, Crucita, Ayampe)</span>
    </label>
</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="vertical-center">
    <input type="submit" id="mc-subscribe" value="Subscribe">
  </div>
```

[see subscribe button here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia0g4.jpg)

Comment: I suggest to clean up the html code first. Some inputs are wrapped inside labels while others are not, there's a closing label tag w/out an opening one, then there's an opening label tag w/out a closing one. And why not put the submit button in its own <div class="row">?

Comment: Thank you Volkerschulz, this is new to me and I am trying what LS wrote is working perfectly. Thank you again for assistance.

Comment: Just trying to help. If I were you I'd fix it anyways, as it might look different in different browsers. Some are tolerant to invalid html while others are not.

Comment: thank you what LS wrote me is doing great, they rewrote it all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="container" id="mcemail">
    <form class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div>
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="first name" required="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="LNAME" placeholder="last name" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div>
                <label>Email address:
                    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Your email address" required />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Which List to signup for</label>
                <label>
                    <input name="_mc4wp_lists[]" type="checkbox" value="Cotacachi"> <span>Cotacachi</span>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input name="_mc4wp_lists[]" type="checkbox" value="Quito"> <span>Quito</span>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input name="_mc4wp_lists[]" type="checkbox" value="Delivery (Cuenca, Olon, Manta, Puerto Lopez, Puerto Cayo, Bahia, Crucita, Ayampe)"> <span>Delivery (Cuenca, Olon, Manta, Puerto Lopez, Puerto Cayo, Bahia, Crucita, Ayampe)</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vertical-center">
            <input type="submit" id="mc-subscribe" value="Subscribe">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I cleaned up the HTML a bit and put the `<form>` tag in and put the submit button inside the form tag.